# CodeBlock undefined reference to PQconnectdb

Tags: c, postgresql, codeblocks, libpq

i created a new project and copy libpq.lib and header in specific directory of my project.
I also add linker destination but when i build i get an undefined reference.

So i forgot something but what ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Things you forgot are more details. Missing are e.g. your system, your OS, your compiler, the actual commands you entered, the actual output of your compiler.

Comment: system => windows 10 compiler gcc and trying to build

Comment: -------------- Build: Debug in PGlib (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Llib -L"..\..\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\lib" -o bin\Debug\PGlib.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\src\cBase.o  -llibpq  
obj\Debug\src\cBase.o: In function `ZN5cBaseC2ENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES5_S5_':
D:/Dev/PGlib/src/cBase.cpp:10: undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: #include <string>

#include <libpq-fe.h>   
cBase::cBase(string DbName,string UserLogin,string PassWord)
{
    m_DbName = DbName;
    m_UserLogin = UserLogin;
    m_PassWord = PassWord;

    const char *conninfo = "hostaddr = '127.0.0.1' dbname = 'Serveur_Atlantis' user = 'MyUser' password = 'MonMDP'";
    PGconn *conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);
}

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem !
Code blocks is a 32 bits version and Postgrel in 64.
So i get the 32 bits binaries from https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries and its work.